# Segmentation fault on properly allocated array

Tags: c++, c

I get a segmentation fault while assigning values to what looks to me a properly allocated array. Here is the code below:

```
int SpV = L*L*L;
int V = SpV*T;
int M = 16;
int Ns = 2;
int Np = 10;

float *twopBuf = (float*) malloc(Np*Ns*V*M*2*sizeof(float));
if(twopBuf == NULL){
  fprintf(stderr,"Cannot allocate twopBuf. Exiting\n");
  exit(-1);
}

for(int bar=0;bar<Np;bar++)
  for(int pr=0;pr<Ns;pr++)
    for(int t=0;t<T;t++)
      for(int v=0;v<SpV;v++)
        for(int gm=0;gm<M;gm++){
          int pos = 2*gm + 2*M*v + 2*M*SpV*t + 2*M*SpV*T*pr + 2*M*SpV*T*Ns*bar;

          twopBuf[ 0 + pos ] = 1.0; // Set to 1.0 for
          twopBuf[ 1 + pos ] = 1.0; // testing purposes
        }
```

L and T are input, so when say `L = 32` and `T = 64` it runs fine. But for `L = 48` and `T = 96` I get segmentation fault after `bar` becomes 2 and before it becomes 3. If there wasn't enough memory to allocate `twopBuf` wouldn't I already get the error message?

I'm running this on the head node of a large supercomputer, if it makes a difference. Thanks.

Comment: `6794772480 > INT_MAX` for 32-bit `int`. Solution: `malloc(sizeof(float)*Np*Ns*V*M*2);` for 64-bit `size_t`.

Comment: Please decide whether you are using C or C++ and tag appropriately. It looks like plain C, apart from the malloc casts, which are only required for C++.

Comment: @EOF That is the answer. Please post.

Comment: `malloc` in C++? What?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I added the C++ tag by mistake. Nevertheless when using C I almost always cast my pointers. By the way, I'm a physicist, not a programmer, don't be that hard at me :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression

```
Np*Ns*V*M*2*sizeof(float)
```

is evaluated as

```
((((Np*Ns)*V)*M)*2)*sizeof(float)
```

due to the left-to-right associativity of `*` in C and C++. See C11 draft standard n1570, *6.5.5 Multiplicative operators*.

The type of an expression `E1 * E2` is the common real type of the operands (*6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions*). In this case, the types are

```
((((int*int)*int)*int)*int)*size_t
```

so all but the last multiplication is done at `int`-precision and range.
For L = 48, T = 96 and `sizeof(float) == 4`, the infinitely precise result of the `int`-precision multiplications is `6794772480`, which is not representable in 16- or 32-bit `int`, so one of the multiplications must overflow on such an implementation, which is *undefined behavior*.

If the expression is reordered to:

```
sizeof(float)*Np*Ns*V*M*2
```

all of the multiplications are done at `size_t` precision, unless `int` can represent all values `size_t` can represent. If the multiplications are done at `size_t`-precision, the multiplication is well-defined even if it overflows, since `size_t` is unsigned. However, if it *does* overflow, `malloc()` will return an allocation that is significantly smaller than you expect, which causes undefined behavior if you access beyond the end of the allocated object.

For the numbers you have provided, 64-bit `size_t` will not overflow if `size_t` has less than 30 padding bits.

Comment: Unfortunately, reordering the expression as indicated didn't solved the problem. How can I determine if I'm using 32-bit `size_t` or 64-bit `size_t`?

Comment: You can check `sizeof(size_t) * CHAR_BIT` (requires `#include <limits.h>`) to find out how many bits `size_t` occupies. Unfortunately this doesn't tell you how many padding-bits the size includes, so you should instead find out what `SIZE_MAX` is on your platform, and compare that to `27179089920`.

Comment: Looking into `<stdint.h>`, I see the following regarding `SIZE_MAX`:
`# if __WORDSIZE == 64`

`#  define SIZE_MAX              (18446744073709551615UL)`

`# else`

`#  define SIZE_MAX              (4294967295U)`

`# endif`

Now, `__WORDSIZE` is defined in `wordsize.h` as:

`#if defined __x86_64__`

`# define __WORDSIZE     64`

`# define __WORDSIZE_COMPAT32    1`

`#else`

`# define __WORDSIZE     32`

`#endif`

Comment: If you want to read through header files manually, you'll need to check `__WORDSIZE` in this case. If you're sane, you'll write a tiny test program that `printf("SIZE_MAX: %zu", SIZE_MAX);`es the value for you, and compile it like the original program.

Comment: Also, note that the change in this answer only fixes the *allocation* of the memory. In your code calculating the index for your access, you are still using `int`-precision, overflowing and causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, I already realized this, it looks like the problem is fixed by using a `long long int pos` variable.

Comment: @physicsCoder No, it's *not* fixed by making `pos` a `long long int`. The type of `pos` does not affect the calculation of the value on the right side of the assignment. The sane way to solve this is to make all of your current `int` variables into `size_t`s.

Comment: I think not all variables need to be declared as `size_t`. After defining `pos` as

`long long int pos = (long long int)(2*gm + 2*M*v + 2*M*SpV*t + 2*M*SpV*T*pr + 2*M*SpV*T*Ns*bar);`

while the rest of the variables are still of type `int` did the trick for me.

Comment: @physicsCoder: It's nice you think this is OK, but it's not. The last term `2*M*SpV*T*Ns*bar` alone causes undefined behavior for signed integer overflow if `INT_MAX == 2147483647`(typical 32-bit two's complement integer) if you substitute the largest values the variables will have in your loops. **Undefined behavior**.